# Safe casting a regexp match from REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with some code points (e.g. &#38) which I want to strip out from a text value in BigQuery.

My strategy is to use a regexp replace on the number replacing the number with the valid character.

If I try:

```
WITH items as (SELECT "Test &#38; " as item)
SELECT
  CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING([SAFE_CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(item, r"&#([0-9]{2})") AS INT64)]) as test_replace
FROM items
```

This will produce the output that I want for the entry

```
[
  {
    "test_replace": "&"
  }
]
```

If I try:

```
WITH items as (SELECT "Test &#38; " as item)
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    item, 
    r"&#([0-9]{2});", 
    CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING([SAFE_CAST("\\1" as INT64)])
    ) as full_replace
FROM items
```

This will produce a null output

```
[
  {
    "full_replace": null
  }
]
```

However if I hard code the value in:

```
WITH items as (SELECT "Test &#38; " as item)
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    item, 
    r"&#([0-9]{2});", 
    CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING([SAFE_CAST("38" as INT64)])
    ) as full_replace
FROM items
```

This works.

```
[
  {
    "full_replace": "Test & "
]
```

I know that the regexp is evaluating correctly as if I try:

```
WITH items as (SELECT "Test &#38; " as item)
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    item, 
    r"&#([0-9]{2});", 
    CONCAT("\\1", "test")
  ) as part_replace
FROM ITEMS
```

This will return:

```
[
  {
    "part_replace": "Test 38test "
  }
]
```

My question is therefore, how do I get the SAFE_CAST() Function to evaluate the regexp match (it seems to be evaluating the string literal).

Comment: do you have one code point per row as it sounds from your examples?

Comment: Nope, I could have potentially more than one.

Comment: so in this case all above is not even relevant as it is for case when you have just one! are you still interested in one point case or multiple? as this I would expect can be quite different

Comment: Okay, I'm not quite following. If there are two columns with these it would be easy enough to handle I think. I was thinking more about the following case: ```WITH items as (SELECT "Test &#38; and &#38; or &#38;" as item)
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    item, 
    r"&#([0-9]{2});", 
    CONCAT("\\1", "test")
  ) as part_replace
FROM ITEMS``` which seems to work ok: ```[
  {
    "part_replace": "Test 38test and 38test or 38test"
  }
]```

Comment: now i am not following :o)  - I meant - do you have one or few code points per item. like `"Test &#38; abc &#39;"` for example

Comment: Thanks very much for the help btw. To answer: yes, but this seems to work as expected as per my example in the comment above (up until I have the main issue I'm encountering), unless I am missing something. That is to say I can't see why multiple occurences would affect the behaviour.

Comment: but that is actually not the result you wanted for full_replace - right?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a table with some code points (e.g. &#38) which I want to strip out from a text value in BigQuery.

Try approach as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION multiReplace(item STRING, arr ARRAY<STRUCT<x STRING, y STRING>>)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    item = item.replace(arr[i].x, arr[i].y)
  };
  return item;
""";
WITH items AS (
  SELECT "Test &#38; abc &#39; xyz" AS item UNION ALL
  SELECT "abc xyz"
)
SELECT item, multiReplace(item, points) full_replace
FROM (
  SELECT 
    item,
    ARRAY(
      SELECT AS STRUCT val, CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING([SAFE_CAST(SUBSTR(val, -3, 2) AS INT64)]) point
      FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(item, r'(&#[0-9]{2};)')) val
    ) points
  FROM items
)
```

with result

```
Row item                        full_replace     
1   Test &#38; abc &#39; xyz    Test & abc ' xyz     
2   abc xyz                     abc xyz
```

> Option 2

While the simplest way to approach above is

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION multiReplace(item STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var decodeHtmlEntity = function(str) {
    return str.replace(/&#([0-9]{2});/g, function(match, dec) {
      return String.fromCharCode(dec);
    });
  };
  return decodeHtmlEntity(item);
""";
WITH items AS (
  SELECT "Test &#38; abc &#39; xyz" AS item UNION ALL
  SELECT "abc xyz"
)
SELECT item, multiReplace(item) full_replace
FROM items
```

with the same output

Comment: Option 2 was perfect for me, thanks so much fort the help. I've learned quite a bit from this.